# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - I dont understand why I am getting this error

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

What is wrong with my code? I am trying to pass two arguments(one for random seed and another for the  and i get the array our of bounds exception error.. I dont understand what i am doing wrong.. I appreciate any help

```
import java.util.Random;

public class sparse {

    public static int size;
    public static int matrix[][] = new int[size][size];
    public static int seed;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        seed = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        size = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        matrix = matrixGen();
    }

    public static int[][] matrixGen() {
        Random r = new Random(seed);
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = r.nextInt(100);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                System.out.print(" " + matrix[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println("  ");
        }

        return matrix;
    }
}
```

Comment: Paste the complete stack trace of the exception, and tell us which line it points to.

Comment: Please don't edit the question to remove essentially all the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must initialize the size of the matrix before allocating the space for it:

```
 public static int size = 30; // or whatever value do you want
```

Comment: He sets it in the constructor

Comment: @Bohemian He does, but he does **not** recalculate matrix-dimensions after that

Comment: the code for matrix initialization, being static, is executed before any constructor and/or function of that class.

Comment: @Bohemian what constructor? I don't see a constructor.

Comment: @Bohemian I was commenting that there is a main method and a function to initialize the matrix but no formal constructor that I can see.

Answer (score 4):

You get the error because you allocate the `matrix` at the time when the `size` is still zero:

```
public static int matrix[][] = new int[size][size]; // size is zero here
```

You need to remove the initialization from the declaration, and move it to the `main()`, after reading the `size` from `args`.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    seed = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    size = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    matrix = new int[size][size];
    matrix = matrixGen();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The static fields seed and size have the default value (0) when you initialize the matrix field.

Thus matrix is a 0x0 array, without space for any element: any access will give such an exception.

To fix, you should set the matrix field in the main function, after arguments' parse.